# Seasonal trend loess (STL) decomposition around holidays

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality, decomposition

I am seasonally adjusting a weekly transaction time-series. The seasonal adjustment works great, except for on and around closed days. At and around these points there are serious errors. What is the proper way to decompose a time series for these localized closed days?

I can think of a couple options

1. on closed days the seasonal adjustment = the observation
2. on closed days the seasonal adjustment = trend
3. remove closed days and days around closed days

For more information, I am using `decompose(type = "multiplicative")`. I have tried `additive`, but had much worse performance.

Comment: Please edit your question to spell out the abbreviation "STL" at its first use, or simply use the full form instead of an abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

Holidays are not something that can be handled by STL decomposition. Instead you should use a model that enables you to include holiday dummies. One such model is [Facebook's prophet](https://research.fb.com/prophet-forecasting-at-scale/), that is able to decompose the time-series to seasonal patterns, trend, include specific dummies, and allow for structural changes by detecting change-points and using them as variables for piecewise regression.